# printing date in different format on x-axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js to build this line chart.and its working fine . but i am not able to print the months on x-axis in abbreviated form (jan,feb....)

here how i am parsing the date.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;
```

the code for x-axis

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
```

and printing and appending

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

help me with this.

Comment: any one please .. ?? dont able to solve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format time on xAxis use d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471224/how-to-format-time-on-xaxis-use-d3-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use tickFormat with a d3.time.format inside

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H"))
```