# abbreviated month format for x-axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how to convert the full month name to abbreviated name by this function

```
axis.ticks(d3.time.months, 1)
```

this function prints the months name in full january February

What should i use to change it to abbreviated names.

Comment: Asking the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522577/printing-date-in-different-format-on-x-axis-in-d3-js) only 20 minutes later isn't the best way to go...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a [timeFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), like this:

```
axis.ticks(d3.time.months, 1)
   .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer was answered before d3 version 4 release. If you want to do the same with d3 version 4, do it like this:

```
axis.ticks(d3.timeMonth, 1)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'));
```