# how to format time on xAxis use d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According the demo on [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oleY4.png)

I don't know how format time on xAxis

this is my code :
js:

```
    var data = [{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 15:09:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "16"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:59:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:49:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "297"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:39:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "31"
        },{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:29:03",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
    }];
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.creat_time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.roundTripTime); });


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.creat_time = parseDate(d.creat_time);
        d.roundTripTime = +d.roundTripTime;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.creat_time; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.roundTripTime;}));

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("return time(ms)");

    svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", line);
```

this is svg:
[image]

In svg , time is 12-hour clock ,but in my data time is 24-hour clock .
 how to keep the same format on svg and data?

Any help is appreciated. (ps:I hope you don't mind my English,it's so bad.)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the tickFormat function on the axis object as below

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H"));
```

The `%H` specifies `hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23]`.  Check this link [D3 time formatting](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#user-content-locale_format) for more information

You can check out a working example in this tributary [24hr time example](http://tributary.io/inlet/5186053)

Comment: i updated the link to the formatting reference since this post led me to the right place plus a few extra clicks - and upvoted

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer is indeed correct, but in my case, I needed the flexibility for the formats to adjust to different scales (think zooming), but also to ensure the 24hr clock is used.  The key is to define a **multi-resolution time format**.  See the [Documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format_multi) page for details.

My code:

```
var axisTimeFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
    [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
    [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
    ["%H:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
    ["%H:%M", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
    ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
    ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
 ]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(axisTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 4):

For a **multi-resolution time format** in d3 v4 and above, `d3.time.multi` has been deprecateed. Instead, define the formats yourself and use a ternary to detect the correct time, using [time intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3-time).

```
var formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat(".%L"),
    formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(":%S"),
    formatMinute = d3.timeFormat("%I:%M"),
    formatHour = d3.timeFormat("%I %p"),
    formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%a %d"),
    formatWeek = d3.timeFormat("%b %d"),
    formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
    formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

function multiFormat(date) {
  return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date ? formatMillisecond
      : d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond
      : d3.timeHour(date) < date ? formatMinute
      : d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour
      : d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? (d3.timeWeek(date) < date ? formatDay : formatWeek)
      : d3.timeYear(date) < date ? formatMonth
      : formatYear)(date);
}
```

When calling an time interval like `d3.timeDay(date)`, it will floor the current date to the day, week and so on.

If the floored date is equal to the current date, then `d3.timeSecond(date) < date` will be false. But if it's smaller (that means, you could floor the date) then it's true and we use the formatter.

In practice:

```
var d = new Date(2020,1,2) // 2020-02-02T00:00

// floor to nearest second
d3.timeSecond(d) // 2020-02-02T00:00, date gets floored but is equal to date 
                 // after flooring, since it already was :00 seconds
d3.timeSecond(d) < d // equal so false, move on to next precision

// ...
// floor to nearest month
d3.timeMonth(d) // 2020-02-01T00:00, date gets floored to months
d3.timeMonth(d) < d // floored date is now smaller, so true, and use month formatter
```

Code from [d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format).

Answer (score 3):

I want to add [this link](https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/zanarmstrong/raw/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95/index.html) to an awesome demo page. It is a playground when you can choose what a format specifier do you need for your case. It is very useful when you do not remember/know what a format specifier you should pass to your `d3.timeFormat` function.

I also want to notice, that if you have d3 version 4, you should use [`d3.timeFormat`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat) function, instead of `d3.time.format`.

Comment: I got `TypeError: d3.timeFormat.multi is not a function`. So are there some other changes that are needed too?

Comment: demo link dead ;-(

Comment: I have updated the link. Now it is live.

Answer (score 2):

In v4,

```
...
var scaleX = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(scaleX)
                   .ticks(d3.timeMinute, 10); // Every 10 minutes
...
```

Note that use `d3.timeMinute` - not `d3.timeMinutes`