# Why d3 time scale only shows me 00:00?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm new to d3 and I'm trying to do some data visualization with it. I found some examples about how to create a time scale in d3, but when I followed the examples and try to create the time scale, it failed. I was frustrated because I couldn't figure out where it went wrong... the example is like this:
[how to format time on xAxis use d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471224/how-to-format-time-on-xaxis-use-d3-js)

So my code is like this:

```
    boxplotdata =[]
    boxplotdata.push(
    {"datetime":"2013-10-30 01:47",length: 500, start:100,deep1_a:130,deep1:50,deep2_a:200,deep2:60,deep3_a:280,deep3:50,deep4_a:350,deep4:60},
    {"datetime":"2013-10-31 01:45",length: 600, start:200,deep1_a:230,deep1:60,deep2_a:300,deep2:60,deep3_a:380,deep3:50,deep4_a:450,deep4:60},
    {"datetime":"2013-11-01 02:11",length: 550,start:150,deep1_a:180,deep1:50,deep2_a:250,deep2:60,deep3_a:350,deep3:50,deep4_a:410,deep4:60},
    {"datetime":"2013-11-02 01:59",length: 500,start:160,deep1_a:190,deep1:80,deep2_a:300,deep2:60,deep3_a:370,deep3:50,deep4_a:430,deep4:60},          
);

//SET MARGIN FOR THE CANVAS
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").parse; 

//SET X AND Y
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([0,11])
    .range([50, width]);

var y = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(boxplotdata[0].datetime),d3.time.day.offset(new Date(boxplotdata[boxplotdata.length-1].datetime),1)])
    .rangeRound([20, height-margin.top- margin.bottom]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"))
    //.ticks(d3.time.minutes,15)
    //.tickPadding(8);  

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('right')
    .ticks(d3.time.days,1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m-%d'))
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(8);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.datetime); });


var w=960,h=1000;



  d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg").remove(); //Old canvas must be removed before creating a new canvas.
  var svg=d3.select("#chart").append("svg") 
          //.attr("width",w).attr("height",h);            
            .attr("width",w+margin.right+margin.left).attr("height",h+margin.top+margin.bottom) 
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");                

boxplotdata.forEach(function(d) {
    d.datetime = parseDate(d.datetime);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(boxplotdata, function(d) { return d.datetime; }));



  bars = svg.selectAll("g")
       .data(boxplotdata)
       .enter()
       .append("g");
```

some drawing codes here..., and at last:

```
     svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      //.attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(yAxis);
```

However, when I tried, I could only get a graph with all time on the xAxis shown as "00:00". What's going wrong here? Hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is from different days, so what's happening here is that D3 is picking representative values (i.e. the boundaries between days) and making ticks for that. As your date format only shows hour and minute, 00:00 is all you get.

You have basically two options here. You could either change the date format to show days (which is what D3 intends), or you could set the tick values explicitly to whatever you want. For the first, you could use e.g. `d3.time.format("%a")`. For the second, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues).

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use the tickFormat function on the axis

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H"));