# d3.js refactoring bar chart and is it overkill to provide meta data to handle different scales?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to refactor a bar chart to look more like the designs.

[image]
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yu2qzxsn/

Do I need to also provide the chart here with metadata like if the xaxis will be a date or a number field? I think the designer would be expecting thinner bars.

```
                var yLabel = "";
                var margin = methods.getMargin();

                var minLimit = 0;
                var maxLimit = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value;} );                       

                methods.setDimensions(w, h, margin);

                methods.setX();
                methods.setY();

                var svg = d3.select(methods.el["selector"]).append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "barchart")
                    .attr("width", methods.width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height",methods.height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                  methods.x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
                  methods.y.domain([minLimit, maxLimit]);

                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + methods.height + ")")
                      .call(methods.xAxis);

                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "y axis")
                      .call(methods.yAxis)
                    .append("text")
                      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                      .attr("y", 6)
                      .attr("dy", ".71em")
                      .style("text-anchor", "end")
                      .text(yLabel);


                this.barrects = svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "barrects")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")

                    methods.animateBars(data);


                function type(d) {
                  d.value = +d.value;
                  return d;
                }
```

Comment: Do you need to reduce the size of the bars or need to do something else

Comment: Maybe reduce the widths of the bars -- but also prepare the chart to take on different scales -- if it be a date - or a number

Comment: Look following reference for time formatting in x-axis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471224/how-to-format-time-on-xaxis-use-d3-js?rq=1

Comment: Sure man -- What I mean - is - is there a clean way -- to just pump data into this bar chart module - and build it in a way, that the chart understands its a date or number scale

Comment: Latest jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yu2qzxsn/6/