# change axis labels in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

how i can change the date format in my chart axis?

i want it formatted like this - "11/08"

```
var hourDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["CR_DATE"]; })
var HourCalc = hourDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d["AMOUNT"];})
width(600)
        .height(160)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
        .dimension(hourDim)
        .group( HourCalc)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxisLabel("DATE").xUnits(d3.time.days)
        .yAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return NumberFormat(v) ;})
```

Comment: this has been asked a few dozen times - the trick is to search for d3.js, not dc.js when looking for axis help, because dc.js just uses the d3 axis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format time on xAxis use d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471224/how-to-format-time-on-xaxis-use-d3-js)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522577/printing-date-in-different-format-on-x-axis-in-d3-js